# Is it possible to keep all shape layers outline on at all times in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, shapes

I have a vector image I've created in illustrator which I would like to turn into pixel art. I've imported my vector as a shape layer in photoshop, and I was hoping to use the outlines of it as a guide (as the image is 64 x 64 in size, a raster guide would not have the same detail).

[image: vector sketch]

Is it possible to keep a shape layer's outlines visible, even if it is not selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, no. The outline of a vector/shape layer only appears when it is selected. There is no way to indicate the outline being selected, unless the path is selected.